# What is the type of "children" in nested routes in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Given the following code, what is the type of "children"?  It seems like it is most likely just `React.Component` but I'm not sure and have been unable to figure this out simply by perusing the code.  Given that you can have a "components" in the Route, I'm definitely unsure.

Furthermore using just `React.Component` fails due to a compiler error "error TS2314: Generic type 'Component' requires 2 type argument(s)" so perhaps I could do `React.Component<{}, {}>`

```
export class App extends React.Component<{children}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React Router Tutorial</h1>
                <ul role="nav">
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/repos">Repos</Link></li>
                </ul>

                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="/repos" component={Repos}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

For clarification, I'll also ask this in another way: say I wanted to replace that first line with the following, what type would I give `children`, rather than `any`

```
interface {
    children: /* ??? something besides any */ any
}

export class App extends React.Component<AppProps, {}> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: I just discovered `ReactInstance` in react.d.ts which is just a type alias for `Component<any, any> | Element` -- this also seems promising :D

Comment: It seems that React.ReactElement<{}> is more appropriate actually.

Comment: I wonder if children here is actually part of React (not react-router), and props should just be something that extends React.Props; React.Props contains a "children" property of type ReactNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the correct way to do this is demonstrated in [react-router.d.ts in DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react-router/react-router.d.ts)  *(Specifically, pay attention to [line 83](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react-router/react-router.d.ts#L83) as of 2/20/2016 at 10:08PM MST which defines RouterProps, the equivalent Props interface for the well known Router component.)*

In the React typings, there is a Props interface which contains, among other properties that are standard to React components, `children`.

The code sample transforms, therefore, into the following. Note especially the interface at the top.

```
interface AppProps extends React.Props<App> { }

export class App extends React.Component<AppProps, {}> {
    /* ... */
}
```